# Descartes rule of signs

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I'm trying to write an algorithm that gets a polynomial and gives how many roots does it have in the interval [0 $x_0$].
I'm supposed to do it by Descartes law, I know that by Descartes law you Know at most how many roots do you have so I'm looking for a hint how can it tell me for sure in  an interval.
If I check what is the value at $y(0)$ and $y(x_0)$  if they are different signs so I have an odd number of roots and if they are the same sign I will have an even number (can be zero). So lets say I know from Descartes law that  I have at most 2 positive roots and $y(0)$ and $y(x_0)$ are the same sign how can I know if the roots are in my interval if I have any at all.

Thanks

Comment: Did you look into Sturm chains resp.sequences? Some M. Vincent wrote in 1834 an algorith that only uses the Descartes law of sign in its extension, the Budan-Fourier theorem. Modern implementations have equal or better complexity than the Sturm procedure.